# Property valid indication in a C# class for value type properties

Tags: c#, validation

I have a data stream that updates only parts of a full object each time. So of 10 properties, only 1 can actually be valid. I will anyways create a new instance of my class, but with only one property with valid data.

I want to be able to indicate if a property is containing real data, and keeping the property a value type (so no nullable types). And all values are possible (so no 'INT_MAX' indicates invalid).

Previously I have used an int32 as a binary mask to indicate valid properties, but that obviously has a limitation on the number of properties, and in a class hierarchy it becomes messy.
I also applied get'ers on the mask, so a boolean SomePropertyIsValid-property was available, and that helped, but it doubled the properties made available.

I'm heading towards using a bit-mask again, unless there are someone that has a great idea?

---

Addition:
I read a steam of UDP packages (~100k per sec) that comes from a third party. They are coded like this:

```
int32 id;     // Unique system id of the object being updated
int32 mask;   // indicates which fields that are included in the message
int32 fieldA; // If mask bit 0 is high
float fieldB; // If mask bit 1 is high
int32 fieldC; // If mask bit 2 is high
int32 fieldD; // If mask bit 3 is high
int32 fieldE; // If mask bit 4 is high
```

I have created a class that deserializes the UDP message. I create a new instance, or update an excising one if data from the same object id has been received before.

My class exposes all the fields as properties defined by an interface:

```
public interface IMessage
{
  int Id {get; set;}
  int FieldA {get; set;}
  double FieldB {get; set;}
  int FieldC {get; set;}
  int FieldD {get; set;}
  int FieldE {get; set;}
}
```

Now how do I indicate which properties that are actually updated?
Pair and nullable types will double (or more) the memory used, so using a bit-mask (like the third party data source uses) doesn't seem like a bad idea, but I just wanted to check if there was some other nifty trick that doesn't have a large performance impact.

Comment: What do you mean? Show somne code. Why would you want to keep 10 properties if you're not using them?

Comment: Why no to `Nullable<T>` ? Can you explain your problem in code?

Comment: Indeed - a nullable value type *is* still a value type.

Answer (score 0):

How about subclassing to 10 different classes each one containing one property?

Based on your need (actually one property at a time) i think this is more suitable. Then you could try the 'as' operator to check which subclass you have and use it's property...

Comment: So like using boxing and un-boxing? It has crossed my mind, but it has quite a impact on performance. Sorry for not stating that that was a criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Use getter and setter for each property, then you can throw an exception when you get value from this property withou proper initialization, and then handling this exception.

The other option if you don't want to use exception and don't want to double the numbers of properties, your properties could return KeyValuePair or Tuple

Comment: Thank you. KeyValuePair or Tuple are good suggestions, but I forgot to mentioned that I can't allow for much overhead.

Comment: Use the exception technique then

Answer (score 0):

Nullable, bitmasks, boolean IsXXValid properties, whatever.  You have options.

**BUT**  Are you going about things the right way?  This sounds like a poor design decision.  I don't know enough about the project to help.

If it's common that only one (or a few) of these properties are actually set, why not use a Dictionary.  If the property doesn't exist, then it's not set.

You could also have fun with dynamic objects.  Both of these options aren't as statically-typed as what you're discussing, but may solve the problem better.

Oh, regarding Nullable:
If a property is Nullable, you can use it like `object.Property.Value` and it will throw an exception if it's null.  Sounds easy.

Comment: Hehe, you are right: It is a poor design, but I'm not able to change the data source. And I can't afford to wait for a complete set of data has been transmitted. Dynamics has always felt intimidating :)